# Compute cost of an Item?

Tags: math, computation, gstreamer

im not sure if i say it right.

my question is how can i get the COST of an item if then given is the Net and the GST?

Comment: This really doesn't belong here. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic equation is:

```
net = cost + (gst * cost) = cost * (1.0 + gst)
```

(with `gst` expressed as a decimal)

Therefore by algebra (dividing both sides by `1.0 + gst`) you have:

```
cost = net / (1.0 + gst)
```

Comment: Or to make it really obvious, `cost = net / 1.1` when gst is 10%